# How to create table like structure in Python for alternative to avoid nesting of lists problem?

Tags: python

I want to store data in a table like structure.
The way i will populate it is generation of row after complex processing into different section of the codebase.

```
def insert_into_list(col1,col2,col3...):
   mytable=[]
   mytable.append([col1,col2,upper(col3)...])
   
   return mytable
```

my ideal table will be of below structure:

```
mytable=[
['john','doe','michigan',5000],
['jane','doe','michigan',10000],
['mona','johnson','florida',20000],
['sami','kahn','georgia',20000],
...and so on
]
```

Issue with using append is that mytable list is getting converted  to a nested list at more than 2 levels and I am unable to do post processing on it easily.

On the other hand using insert() I am getting error with insert that only 2 values are allowed and as you can see from my example my table has more than 3 columns atleast

If I try to use pandas dataframe using append function, it threw error the append function in it is going to be deprecated and use concact. And concat is not easy to work with :|

Questions:

1. How can i modify the my use of list functions i.e. append or insert to correctly do it?
2. Should i explore some other data structure instead of list to do this kind of work? If what options do you suggest to look . The criteria is that data structure should be easy to move around in various functions and different .py files

You may ask why I am programming like this.
I have been a Oracle Database Administrator  dba and i am used to thinking table to be something like this :

| first | last | state | salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | michigan | 5000 |
| jane | doe | michigan | 10000 |
| mona | johnson | florida | 20000 |
| sami | kahn | georgia | 20000 |

Comment: Have you looked at pandas?

Comment: Pandas dataframes are by far the most common way to do this. If `concat` isn't working for you, ask a question specifically about that.

Comment: It's not clear what problems you're having exactly with append and insert. For help with that, you'd need to provide a [mre], but like others have said, Pandas is a better fit for this kind of work, so it'd be better to focus on that.

Comment: This url has the exact examples that i used to solve my question using concat. https://www.stackvidhya.com/add-row-to-dataframe/

Answer (score 1):

Most people use either a pandas dataframe or a numpy 2D array. Both are good options, although pandas tends to give more functionality (and it is built on top of numpy in any case).

If concat is giving you trouble, you should be able to do the same thing you are doing with your list and just add items row by row by using `df.loc()` or `df.iloc()`.

I found a good example for you here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-one-row-in-an-existing-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Pandas documentation discourages row by row inserting.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html Note

Adding a column to a DataFrame is relatively fast. However, adding a row requires a copy, and may be expensive. We recommend passing a pre-built list of records to the DataFrame constructor instead of building a DataFrame by iteratively appending records to it.

Comment: I will test what you suggested though

Comment: Adding a row here and there is totally fine; what they're saying that when initially creating your DataFrame, you'd want to do it all at once, from a list (along the lines of what you already have), rather than building it up one row at a time in a `for` loop.

Comment: @KrishSingh You are definitely right that row by row isn't the best option, but since that is how your code was already set up I figured it was the easiest thing. If your code needs to scale, there are probably better ways to do it.